# Background Mode doesn't be added in Xcode

Tags: xcode, background-mode

I want to add Background Mode to use Location Updates but I can't.
I already know the place of Background Mode but I don't know why it doesn't work.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7CeRiios1vD51u3OmM1qTAs7AxVVmE6/view?usp=sharing

I recorded the situation so you can see it in that link.

Comment: You can try adding the same in Info.plist

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the solution thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

this code to Info.plist.